# Rails 4 Error: NoMethodError - undefined method `itemfavorites'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nomethoderror

Hey I am receiving an issue when accessing `@interestedusers = User.itemfavorites.where(item_id: @item.id)` from my `ItemsController`:

```
NoMethodError in ItemsController#show
undefined method `itemfavorites' for #<Class:0xfb94bb8>
```

*Routes*

```
resources :items do
    get :itemfavorites, on: :member
end
```

*User Model*

```
# Favorite items of user
has_many :favorite_items # just the 'relationships'
has_many :itemfavorites, through: :favorite_item, source: :item # the actual items the user favorites
```

*Item Model*

```
# Favorited by users
has_many :favorite_items # just the 'relationships'
has_many :itemsfavorited_by, through: :favorite_items, source: :user # the actual users favoriting an item
```

**The general association works, I tested it and I can add/remove and display favorites.**

I am trying to display the users favorited an Item.

Thanks in advance for each answer! Please tell me if you need additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling itemfavorites on the User class, not a User instance. I guess you want to do something like

```
@interestedusers = current_user.itemfavorites.where(item_id: @item.id)
```

or

```
@interestedusers = @user.itemfavorites.where(item_id: @item.id)
```

EDIT: you want to do this to get users for an item:

```
@interestedusers = @item.itemsfavorited_by
```

Comment: `current_user` works. Problem is that I want to get a User(model). With your suggested way I get an Item(model)

Comment: get a user? what do you mean?

Comment: If I am looping through this I want to get access to the user table of my database and with that solution I get access to the Items table :)